# How to prevent the character from escaping out of the box?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, maze, python-turtle

So, I've been trying to make a maze using python, and it's been going well, except that I can't stop the character from getting out of the maze's box! This is my code:

```
import turtle

wn = turtle.Screen()
wn.setup(width=1000, height=700)
wn.bgcolor('white')
wn.title('test')
wn.tracer(0)

box_1 = turtle.Turtle()
box_1.shape('square')
box_1.penup()
box_1.color('black')
box_1.goto(-485, 0)
box_1.shapesize(stretch_len=1.5, stretch_wid=35)

box_2 = turtle.Turtle()
box_2.shape('square')
box_2.penup()
box_2.color('black')
box_2.goto(-500, -95)
box_2.shapesize(stretch_len=35, stretch_wid=1.5)

box_3 = turtle.Turtle()
box_3.shape('square')
box_3.penup()
box_3.color('black')
box_3.goto(-325, 0)
box_3.shapesize(stretch_len=1.5, stretch_wid=10)

box_4 = turtle.Turtle()
box_4.shape('square')
box_4.penup()
box_4.color('black')
box_4.goto(-145, -180)
box_4.shapesize(stretch_len=1.5, stretch_wid=10)

box_4 = turtle.Turtle()
box_4.shape('square')
box_4.penup()
box_4.color('black')
box_4.goto(-240, -265)
box_4.shapesize(stretch_len=10, stretch_wid=1.5)

box_4 = turtle.Turtle()
box_4.shape('square')
box_4.penup()
box_4.color('black')
box_4.goto(-345, -220)
box_4.shapesize(stretch_len=1.5, stretch_wid=6)

box_4 = turtle.Turtle()
box_4.shape('square')
box_4.penup()
box_4.color('black')
box_4.goto(-190, 90)
box_4.shapesize(stretch_len=15, stretch_wid=1.5)

character = turtle.Turtle()
character.shape('square')
character.speed(0)
character.penup()
character.color('yellow')
character.goto(-485, 335)
character.shapesize(stretch_wid=1, stretch_len=1)


def character_up():
    y = character.ycor()
    y += 10
    character.sety(y)


def character_down():
    y = character.ycor()
    y -= 10
    character.sety(y)


def character_right():
    x = character.xcor()
    x += 10
    character.setx(x)


def character_left():
    x = character.xcor()
    x -= 10
    character.setx(x)


wn.listen()
wn.onkeypress(character_up, "Up")
wn.onkeypress(character_down, "Down")
wn.onkeypress(character_right, "Right")
wn.onkeypress(character_left, "Left")


while True:
    wn.update()
    x = character.xcor()
    y = character.ycor()
```

You can try this out yourself and you'll see that you can just easily get the character out of the maze, but I want to prevent it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I lack the ability to run this code at the moment, but  I could give the following points:

1. Don't reuse the `box_4` variable. Set `box_5`, `box_6`, and `box_7`.
2. In your `character_[up/down/right/left]` functions, check if the X value is above or below a certain value, and don't accept the move if so. For example:

```
def character_up():
    y = character.ycor()
    if (y < 100) { // Only do this if the Y variable is within bounds
        y += 10
    }
    character.sety(y)


def character_down():
    y = character.ycor()
    if (y > -100) {
        y -= 10
    }
    character.sety(y)


def character_right():
    x = character.xcor()
    if (x < 100) {
        x += 10
    }
    character.setx(x)


def character_left():
    x = character.xcor()
    if (x > -100) {
        x -= 10
    }
    character.setx(x)
```

You may have to adjust the bounds (`-100` --> `-200`, `100` --> `200`)

Comment: Ooh, thnx a lot, I think this will fix it!

Comment: I think there's confusion here from the OP's terminology.  I don't think the problem is keeping the character inside an outer perimeter box, but rather force the character to stay within the lines of a maze, which can't be done via simple bounds tests in the move routines.  I'll offer my own solution, but I may be wrong about this.

Comment: @cdlane Yes, I think that some clarification would be nice. I hope one of our answers fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're trying to find a simple way out of a difficult problem.  You want to draw black lines of a maze, and have your yellow character bound to those lines.  Folks often approach this as drawing the *walls* of the maze and keeping the character from moving onto them.  You've reversed this in that everything is a wall and you want to draw the *path*, keeping your character on the path.  We can do this.

The approach here, is we build the path out of homogenous, small square blocks that are turtles.  We keep a `list` of those blocks, and anytime the character moves, we validate the move by making sure they are always within a short distance of some block:

```
from turtle import Screen, Turtle

BLOCK_SIZE = 30
CURSOR_SIZE = 20
CHARACTER_SIZE = CURSOR_SIZE

def character_up():
    character.sety(character.ycor() + CHARACTER_SIZE/2)

    if not any(box.distance(character) < BLOCK_SIZE/2 for box in boxes):
        character.undo()

def character_down():
    character.sety(character.ycor() - CHARACTER_SIZE/2)

    if not any(box.distance(character) < BLOCK_SIZE/2 for box in boxes):
        character.undo()

def character_right():
    character.setx(character.xcor() + CHARACTER_SIZE/2)

    if not any(box.distance(character) < BLOCK_SIZE/2 for box in boxes):
        character.undo()

def character_left():
    character.setx(character.xcor() - CHARACTER_SIZE/2)

    if not any(box.distance(character) < BLOCK_SIZE/2 for box in boxes):
        character.undo()

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(width=1000, height=700)
screen.tracer(False)

box = Turtle()
box.shape('square')
box.penup()
box.color('black')
box.shapesize(BLOCK_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)

boxes = []

box.goto(-485, 335)
box.setheading(270)
for _ in range(23):
    boxes.append(box.clone())
    box.forward(BLOCK_SIZE)

box.backward(9 * BLOCK_SIZE)
box.setheading(0)
for _ in range(13):
    boxes.append(box.clone())
    box.forward(BLOCK_SIZE)

box.backward(8 * BLOCK_SIZE)
box.setheading(90)
for _ in range(7):
    boxes.append(box.clone())
    box.forward(BLOCK_SIZE)

box.setheading(0)
for _ in range(10):
    boxes.append(box.clone())
    box.forward(BLOCK_SIZE)

box.backward(3 * BLOCK_SIZE)
box.setheading(270)
box.forward(7 * BLOCK_SIZE)
for _ in range(6):
    boxes.append(box.clone())
    box.forward(BLOCK_SIZE)

box.setheading(180)
for _ in range(6):
    boxes.append(box.clone())
    box.forward(BLOCK_SIZE)

box.setheading(90)
for _ in range(4):
    boxes.append(box.clone())
    box.forward(BLOCK_SIZE)

box.hideturtle()
screen.tracer(True)

character = Turtle()
character.shape('square')
character.speed('fastest')
character.color('yellow')
character.penup()
character.goto(-485, 335)
character.shapesize(CHARACTER_SIZE / CURSOR_SIZE)

screen.onkeypress(character_up, 'Up')
screen.onkeypress(character_down, 'Down')
screen.onkeypress(character_right, 'Right')
screen.onkeypress(character_left, 'Left')

screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

My maze drawing code may seem complicated, but by using relative drawing of the blocks, instead of absolute positions, it actually simplifies the problem, as we start thinking in a block-oriented coordinate system, instead of pixels.